# session variables lost for some reason

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, session-variables

I try to setup a E-shop. Next to every item I've an `asp:imagebutton` when this imagebutton is clicked I'm checking whehter the session varialbe `session["basket"]` exists or not if not then I add the values in a list (entity class) and I add this list in the session.

if the session is not empty then I retrieve the values from session into List and change the list and then add the list back to session.

**Issue:**

For some reason I loose the session variable, suddenly.  I checked on my watch (time) and it's unpredicatble  sometimes it takes less than 1 minute, sometimes 3 minutes and sometimes 5 minutes etc....

why do I loose the session variable?

I googled and I've found - it can happen if you use `Response.Redirect` - w/o false parameter, or if you're in an `UpdatePanel` etc.

I'm loosing the variable in the same page for the moment.

The whole idea is put in a session variable and do checkout and retrieve the session variable in second `aspx` page... but this is not always working, because most of the case the session variables becomes empty. And sometimes it works.

can someone advice ? what and where do I need to check? 
In some website pages (google) they advice to use caching, but caching is application based, so everybody will retrieve the same value.

In my page any user (authenticated or anynomous user) in other words any user without login should able to order (I'll send invoice to pay upfront)....

I''m not using webfarm, nor web garden... I just checked the IIS - website - session state - It's in process, cookie settings = use cookies, name = asp.net_sessionid, time-out = 20....

please advice?

It's `C#`, `ASPX 3.5`, `IIS7.5`

I DON't have PAGE_LOAD  in my ASPX page.

//  the only place I put the sessoin=null is a linkbutton, for the rest I don't put null in session["basket"]....

```
protected void lnkDeleteAllSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Basket"] = null;
        ReloadBasketItems();

    }

 protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnInit(e);
        //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

        lvJuridisch.ItemDataBound += new EventHandler<ListViewItemEventArgs>(this.lv_ItemDataBound);
        lvJuridisch.DataBound += new EventHandler(lv_DataBound);

    }
```

imgButtonAddtoBasket -> is defined as asp:imagebutton in the asp:listview

```
 protected void imgButtonAddtoBasket_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewDataItem lvi = ((sender as ImageButton).NamingContainer) as ListViewDataItem;
        DataKey currentDataKey = (lvi.NamingContainer as ListView).DataKeys[lvi.DataItemIndex];
        WebShopInfo SingleItem = new WebShopInfo();
        SingleItem.cd_type_pub = currentDataKey[0].ToString();
        SingleItem.no_pub = currentDataKey[1].ToString();
        SingleItem.no_suite_pub = Convert.ToInt32(currentDataKey[2]);
        SingleItem.cd_langue = Convert.ToChar(currentDataKey[3]);
        SingleItem.lb_titre_red = (lvi.FindControl("HiddenfieldProductRed") as HiddenField).Value;

        SingleItem.m_price = Convert.ToDecimal((lvi.FindControl("hiddenField_M_Price") as HiddenField).Value);
        SingleItem.nm_price = Convert.ToDecimal((lvi.FindControl("hiddenField_NM_Price") as HiddenField).Value);
        SingleItem.mt_pourc_tva = Convert.ToDecimal((lvi.FindControl("hfBTW") as HiddenField).Value);


        List<WebShopInfo> lws = new List<WebShopInfo>();
        if (Session["Basket"] == null)
        {

            //Session is empty so add listview to the session....
            //Session.Timeout = 20;  -- I tried this but this is not working too...
            lws.Add(SingleItem);
            Session["Basket"] = lws;
        }
        else
        {
            //Session is not empty so get asp:listview from the session.
            lws = Session["Basket"] as List<WebShopInfo>;

            WebShopInfo wsi = lws.Where(a => a.cd_type_pub == SingleItem.cd_type_pub &&
                                            a.no_pub == SingleItem.no_pub &&
                                            a.no_suite_pub == SingleItem.no_suite_pub &&
                                            a.cd_langue == SingleItem.cd_langue).SingleOrDefault<WebShopInfo>();
            if (wsi != null)
                lws.Remove(wsi);

            if (SingleItem.Count > 0)
                lws.Add(SingleItem);
            Session["Basket"] = lws;
        }

        ReloadBasketItems();
    }
```

Comment: Are you on a web farm ? How is your session configured as ?

Comment: Are you on a web farm or web garden if so you should store your session state on a state server or SQL server.Second option check your web config for a <sessionState timeout="time in minutes"/> tag if there is and it is a short time your session is being timed out.

Comment: Did you check in multiple browsers ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta/@maniacneron: I'not using webfarm, nor web garden... I just checked the IIS - website - session state - It's in process, cookie settings = use cookies, name = asp.net_sessionid, time-out = 20.... I also added sesstionstate timeout="20" in web.config... it it's lost.

Comment: Can you post some code, hope you don't have something like `Session["basket"] = null` in the page_load section ?

Comment: @v4vendetta: I just added the code in my POST.

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like your appdomain is being recycled. Is your `web.config` `compilation` element set in `debug` mode? In debug mode, ASP.NET resets the appdomain every 15 dynamic compilations. When that happens, if your sessions are stored in memory (`InProc` mode - the default), they'll be lost.

FYI, a dynamic compilation will occur whenever a file change happens on your site, like you editing an ASPX file, or an image being generated, or a web.config change.

So either put the site into Release mode (`<compilation debug="false" ... />`), or increase the `numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart` value from 15 in `web.config`, or use a non-volatile session storage mode - e.g. SQL Session State.

Comment: ok let me try Release mode.... but I can't find the word numberOfCompilations in web.config.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart`. See here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Are you losing just that particular variable? - If so, then it is probably some part of your code that is doing this.

If you are losing the entire session object, then unless your session has timed out, the other reason is that if you are using inproc session state at your server and ran out of memory - this recycles your worker process causing you to lose the session value. Check your event log to see if this is the case.

Comment: I'not using webfarm, nor web garden... I just checked the IIS - website - session state - It's in process, cookie settings = use cookies, name = asp.net_sessionid, time-out = 20.... Where can I see in the log: I looked at eventviewer - administratrive events -> can't find here info... where do I need to check? which log?

Comment: I'm just wondering, what in code could be causing it?  I currently have the same issue, but only some variables get lost. I never reassign the value inside the variable, but I do use the variable a lot.

Answer (score 3):

you will be surprised to know the behind the scene the session uses the cache!

have a look at the below(you will find all the common problem about session issue):

http://mmtripathi.blogspot.com/2008/09/session-lost-problem-after.html

http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.com/2009/07/why-sessions-are-terminatedloss.html

http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-won-t-my-session-variables-stick.html

Comment: yeah but most of the issue are common

Answer (score 2):

mesut:

Honestly Session memory can be very volitile. If the application goes down you can loose it, or like you said, if the user's session gets restarted you can loose it. Generally the options for Asp.Net are to store data in:

- ViewState (stored as encrypted text accessable by your code-behind)
- Session Memory (essentially a dictionary, but as above, a little
  volatile)
- ASP.Net's State Service (which stores the values in a    separate
  process. watch out for server farm scenarios)
- Cookies
- Cache
- Url Parameters

Each of these methods has a trade-off in terms of performance, memory, or being dependent on a user's environment. I would try a different method and see if that is more robust for you.

Comment: The user selects the item and in postback I catch the selected item and put in as list then in a session, to keep the values after postback: I put in session because I need the value in another page.... but the session variable is lost in the same page

Comment: You didn't mention SQL State, which is my preferred method.

Comment: @James McCormack -- Ah yeah, totally.

Answer (score 0):

Check out whether you are using `Application Pool` which is shared across multiple web sites/applications, if you are sharing the same `AppPool` with an other web application/site - switch to separate `AppPool`.

The best way is to use server-based session state, in this case you can forget about such issues. See [HOW TO: Configure SQL Server to Store ASP.NET Session State](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604)

Comment: @mesut: Are you experiencing any errors on the Application_Error() level?

Comment: this is dotnetnuke CMS system... I think I don't have application_error -- but I'll try protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnError(e);
            lblMessage.Text = e.ToString();
        }

Comment: I try to apply sql Server session state: I get "Unable to use SQL Server because ASP.NET version 2.0 Session State is not installed on the SQL server. Please install ASP.NET Session State SQL Server version 2.0 or above. 
"   I checked my Database and I see the necessary tables are created like aspnet_XXXX etc.. what could be the problem?

Comment: Tou should ask admins to install it