# C#: Random partial loss of values saved in Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I got a single page application which is heavily accessed simultaneously by around 150 users through iPad or Samsung tabs. Now in some scenarios (5-10 of 150) some session variables get lost (not all).

Firstly I thought there must be some erratic code that might be resetting session value but I couldn't find any such instance. I have verified that its not

- app pool recycle
- Maximum Worker Process setting for app pool
- Sessoin.abort
- explicitly setting Session in code

Some more info:

- ASP.NET MVC, backbone
- Server memory: 16 GB
- DB stored on separate server
- session state timeout: 300
- authentication mode: Forms

Now I want to know if its possible that session variables might get lost due to some combination of high user load, multiple reads, number of ajax requests or something else unexpected like this. Or any other pointers towards what I should look next to get this resolved.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: Is it always the same variables that sometimes get lost?

Comment: yes it seems to be like that.

Comment: Have a look here to see if any of these help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814858/session-variables-lost-for-some-reason

Comment: How is your session state stored? In Proc, StateServer, SQL Server?

Comment: Session State is InProc